# How to change the Scene with MouseDown

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, sprite-kit

I'm tring to create a game menu and I got something like this

```
class StartGame: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        let startButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "startGame")
        startButton.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)
        startButton.name = "startButton"
        addChild(startButton) 
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        if(  ...  )
    }
}
```

There ofcourse will be more buttons like "save game", "Exit" and something like that. And there is my question. I'd like to change scene from StartGame to GameScene by clicking the button named "startGame"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `mouseDown` in **StartGame** like this:

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if (node.name == "startButton") {
        let nextScene = GameMenu(size: self.size)
        scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1))
    }
}
```